# Upload Items To SharePoint List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, upload

I have a custom sharepoint list called VSList, from which I can retrieve all items (4 columns altogether) using the following code:

```
string siteUrl = url2;
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("VSList");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(item => item["Title"], item => item["qf2a"], item => item["_x0077_830"], item => item["u6zl"]));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is there any way to reverse it somehow, so I can upload data, and not download it?
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do with the following code (edited my code to fit your list).

```
// Open client context to the site
var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

// Use client context to open the list
var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("VSList");
var listCreationinformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
var oListItem = oList.AddItem(listCreationinformation);

// Push information to individual tables in the selected list
oListItem["Title"] = value1;
oListItem["qf2a"] = value2;
oListItem["_x0077_830"] = value3;
oListItem["u6zl"] = value4;

oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

To get a better overview on how to do this see - [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx)